# How do I structure this kind of sql query

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following database table below
[image]

I want to display notification to the user with `owner_id` 1. The notification show tell the owner that two users (with ids 17 and 2) commented on his/her post with `post_id` 1.
I've tried the following query but it returns 2 rows instead. How can I can structure the query to return one row, because I want the notifications for one post to be returned together? Thank you.

```
SELECT DISTINCT commenters_id, id, owner_id, 
                post_id, type, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_done) AS date 
FROM notification 
GROUP BY commenters_id 
HAVING owner_id = '$user_id' AND commenters_id != '$user_id' 
ORDER BY date_done DESC
```

Comment: So, if you only want one row returned, how do you want to tell that two people have replied to it? Do you prefer the list of replying people to be comma-separated in a VARCHAR field? (Eg. `'2,17'`). Or.. oh! You only want the count?

Comment: @ANisus yes, I want the count first, then I'll separate the returned grouped commenters_id. Sounds absurd to me now.

Comment: What do you mean with "separate the returned grouped commenters_id"? When you group commenters_id, you can either get the MAX, MIN, COUNT, etc. You will not get a list of id's that you later on can split into separate id's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will not give you the commenters_id, but instead a count of how many people have replied to each post. The `date` will be the last time someone replied to that specific post:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT commenters_id) AS commenter_count,
    owner_id,
    post_id,
    type,
    UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(date_done)) AS date 
FROM notification
WHERE owner_id = '$user_id' AND commenters_id != '$user_id' 
GROUP BY owner_id, post_id, type
ORDER BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(date_done)) DESC
```

Comment: Hey I added DISTINCT to to COUNT(commenters_id) and it gave me something interesting. Thanks.

Comment: @Chibuzo: Ah! Of course. That was a bug in my code. I have edited it and added the DISTINCT. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT(commenters_id)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get a comma-separated list of commenter IDs for the post. But then you have to group by post rather than commentor, so the query would look something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(commenters_id), id, owner_id, 
                post_id, type, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_done) AS date 
FROM notification 
GROUP BY post_id 
HAVING owner_id = '$user_id' AND commenters_id != '$user_id' 
ORDER BY date_done DESC
```

GROUP_CONCAT allows some processing of the data if you need it, like returning only distinct values or sorting the values. See the full documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Mysql has GROUP_CONCAT? Neat! I so would like that in MS Sql-server!

Comment: Thanks, but I got the error - Unknown column 'commenters_id' in 'having clause'. Please how do I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that you select the date_done column, too, which makes the rows unique. 
Neither `DISTINCT` nor `GROUP BY` are allowed to group the result set under this circumstances.

Leave the column out of this query or use something like `MAX(date_done)`

EDIT:
wait...you already get only two rows, not four ? Isn't that the result that you wanted? maybe I missunderstood the question

Comment: I just tried it without the date_done, it still returned the same result.